# reduce Itemize space in cv description

Tags: spacing, itemize

I am using the fortyseconds CV template (`fortysecondscv`) and would like to add bulletpoints (squared) in the job description. I must say I don't know anything about LaTeX. I only used it for my thesis many years ago.

First problem: If I enter as argument to the

```
\cvitem
```

a

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item Level 0 Item 0
  \item Level 0 Item 1
\end {itemize}
```

it has ugly large spaces. Is it possible to reduce them?

[image: large spaces]

If I add

```
[topsep=0ex]
```

it does not work.

Second problem: The signature at the bottom of the page needs two lines, due to my long name. Can I change it so that it only needs one line?

[image]

Here still a larger part of the CV:

```
\begin{document}

\makefrontsidebar

\cvsection{Beruflicher Werdegang}
\begin{cvtable}[1]
    \cvitem{currently}{CEO The Panda Way}{Start Up}
    {\begin{itemize}
  \item Level 0 Item 0
  \item Level 0 Item 1
  \end {itemize}
 Chief executive officer, Head
        developer and yoga ambassador of 'The Panda Way' - A company from pandas
        for pandas.}
\end{cvtable}



\cvsignature

\end{document}
```

```
% FortySecondsCV LaTeX template


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                             ADDITIONAL PACKAGES
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[a4paper]{fortysecondscv}

%linkedin symbol
\usepackage{fontawesome}

% take care of proper font encoding
\ifxetexorluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
%   \newfontfamily\headingfont[Path = fonts/]{segoeuib.ttf} % local font
\else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%   \usepackage[sfdefault]{noto} % use noto google font
\fi

% enable mathematical syntax for some symbols like \varnothing
\usepackage{amssymb}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                            PERSONAL INFORMATION
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% mandatory information
% your name
\cvname {Peter-has \\ A-long-name}
% job title/career
\cvjobtitle{Dipl.-Ing.\,(FH)\,Maschinenbau }
%% optional information
% profile picture
\cvprofilepic{pics/profile.png}

% NOTE: ordering in sidebar will mimic the following order
% date of birth
\cvbirthday{01.01.1984}
% short address/location, use \newline if more than 1 line is required
\cvaddress{Teststreet~999, 11111 Berlin}
% phone number
\cvphone{+49 123 456 78}

% email address
\cvmail{Peter-has.a-long-name@gmail.com}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                         TABLE ENTRIES RIGHT COLUMN
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makefrontsidebar

\cvsection{Beruflicher Werdegang}
\begin{cvtable}[1]
    \cvitem{currently}{CEO The Panda Way}{Start Up}
    {\begin{itemize}
  \item Level 0 Item 0
  \item Level 0 Item 1
  \end {itemize}
 Chief executive officer, Head
        developer and yoga ambassador of 'The Panda Way' - A company from pandas
        for pandas.}
\end{cvtable}



\cvsignature

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Sorry for the question, but how can I make it compatible?

Comment: Compilable. Start the code snippet with `\documentclass` and end it with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It was probably not intended by the creators of this document class that you place an `itemize` environment inside the argument of the `\cvitem` macro.

Comment: the last code block contains hast the `\documentclass` and `\end{document}` you can compile it @JasperHabicht does this mean, I can't do anything?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX.SX!

It was probably not intended by the creators of this document class that you place an `itemize` environment inside the fourth argument of the `\cvitem` macro, because from the definition of this macro we can see that this argument will be placed inside a `\textcolor` macro, which cannot easily handle complex code such as `itemize` environments.

You can solve this problem by placing the `itemize` environment inside a `\parbox`. This is, however, just a work around and maybe not a very good solution.

Note that the following code only contains those marcros from the `fortysecondscv` document class that are absolutely needed here to recreate the problem. Since you already use this document class, you *don't need any* of the code from the preamble (this is the part of the code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends just before `\begin{document}`) of this code snippet.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%% excerpt of relevant code from `fortysecondscv` documemt class %%%%%
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{itemtextcolor}{black!90}

\newenvironment{cvtable}[1][1]{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}%
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}%
}{%
    \end{tabular*}%
}

\newcommand{\cvitem}[4]{%
    \parbox[t]{0.17\textwidth}{\raggedright #1} &%
    \parbox[t]{0.81\textwidth}{%
        \if\relax\detokenize{#4}\relax%
            \parbox[t]{\linewidth-\widthof{\footnotesize #3}-1em}{\raggedright #2}%
            \hfill {\footnotesize#3}%
        \else%
            \parbox[t]{\linewidth-\widthof{\footnotesize #3}-1em}{\raggedright \textbf{#2}}%
            \hfill {\footnotesize#3} \\%
            \textcolor{itemtextcolor}{#4}%\vspace{\parsep}%
        \fi%
    }\\
}
%%%%% %%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{cvtable}[1]
    \cvitem{currently}{CEO The Panda Way}{Start Up}
    {\parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{itemize}
        \item Level 0 Item 0
        \item Level 0 Item 1
    \end{itemize}}
    Chief executive officer, Head developer and yoga ambassador of `The Panda Way' -- A company from pandas for pandas.}
\end{cvtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As for the signature, since your name will be used by the document class at several different places, I would suggest that you don't place a line break inside the argument to the `\cvname` macro.

Instead, you could redefine the `\cvsignature` macro which has the following definition:

```
\newcommand{\cvsignature}{
    \vfill
    {\large\bfseries\color{maincolor!70}\today \hfill \cvname}
}
```

Just place this snippet somewhere in your preamble and replace `\newcommand` by `\renewcommand`, then change whatever you want inside the defintion of the macro.

I don't know how you would like your signature to look like, but you can replace `\cvname` by your initials or only your last name, for example, which would probably be shorter than your full name.

To give a simple example: To print "J. Doe" instead of your name in the signature, place the following code somewhere before `\begin{document}`:

```
\renewcommand{\cvsignature}{
    \vfill
    {\large\bfseries\color{maincolor!70}\today \hfill J. Doe}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Only to be sure. I copied everything from `\usepackage{calc}`to the `\beginn{document}` (excluded). Than I replaced the eqvivalent of the second part into my code. It seems to me, that there is no change at all. I do not know if I made some misstake

Comment: No, you don't need to copy anything from my code. You only need to place the `itemize` environment inside a `\parbox`. That is, just replace `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}` in your code by `\parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}}`.

Comment: Ok, I did this. Changes nothing at all. But never the less thank you very much for your help

Comment: Well, I just tried with the `fortysecondscv` document class (which I downloaded [from GitHub](https://github.com/PandaScience/FortySecondsCV/blob/master/fortysecondscv.cls)) and the code you provided, and my suggestions *do* work as intended. So, the problem lies probably in some other part of your code that you did not post.

Comment: I'll find a solution for my problem. There are always severals options to solve a problem. Thanks allot